# PC equivalent of Coda?

Tags: windows, development-environment, coda

Can any one recommend a good all-in-one web development tool for Windows.

Something on par with Coda, which is only available for Mac OS X?

Comment: A Mac? :-) No, I haven't seen anything as comprehensive and well designed on the Windows end.

Comment: ive used coda on the mac and love it. ive been using editplus for my pc because of the ftp integration. while editplus is great ... after using coda i had the same question as you. im now using aptana studio but it still doesn't compare. one thing i dislike about aptana is to get php support, you need to install a plug-in. also the ftp tree on the left has a hard time staying synced. every time i make a new file it refreshes and i have to re-navigate the tree.

Comment: deceze and Robert Harvey can eat a fat one. This is a great question... why ever close it, maybe someday a pc program will come along that is as good as coda? Are you guys just jealous?

Comment: I'm using WebMaxtrix which has an editor, sql manager, and deployment support like coda and since it also functions as your web server it is actually a really great alternative. It even has some cool plugins like an iphone or ipad simulator.

Comment: @JustinBull, you should check out phpstorm, it's a fantastic program for php and handles css and html very well, it's no coda but it's not trying to be, the thing I love Coda for is the speed, not only the GUI but the general logical design coupled with the FTP which is so quick I also like the live CSS editing. However, i'm interested to see how fast the live edit is in php storm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not used Coda by myself, but believe that whatever it has, you can find in Sublime Text 2 as well, check it out. For remote files access, you can use an utility like ExpanDrive that mounts remote drive as local disk.

Answer (score 4):

I love [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). I recommend that you try it.

Answer (score 3):

I Tried NotePad++
And it is in fact very cool, However,
it crashes from time to time and it can delete your work! :O, 
sadly i haven't found anything like CODA for the PC
so i'm staying with the mac

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use notepad++ with ftp_synchronize plug-in so you can remotely edit files on server ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, nothing gets close to Coda on mac. It's pretty sad.

Answer (score 1):

I love Coda and use it professionally every day. However, I'm going to check out Aptana Studio and Komodo IDE on the PC---they both look like they could be very good.

Note that Coda is not free (download, $99), so the answer presumably shouldn't be limited to free PC software in order to compare apples to apples (pun intended).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I used PHPed myself, the best for me

Comment: I second this. I have tried all, and I think PHPEd is the best.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked and NetBeans 7.x is about as close as I've found.  Coda is much more than an editor...it does Subversion, has an excellent built-in CSS editor, and allows really elegant local development and publish-to-host workflow.  Even NetBeans is only local or remote, but can't deal with both in one project.  However, NetBeans' MySQL integration is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Coda just a text editor? For Windows there is [notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/about.php).

Comment: Text editor, css gui, terminal, ftp, and site manager.

Comment: no. notice the preview option.  notice the css editor.  notice the ssh and ftp capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I use KomodoEdit and it does not even compare to Coda. Coding on a Mac is a lot different as you can have a built in terminal. A windows equivalent would have to have a plugin for putty or something similar.