# Recommend a simple editor similar to Coda

Tags: windows, coda

I really like this simple, highly specialized editor also has a very nice interface.
Now I'm looking for such an editor available on Windows or Linux. All I found is Komodo Edit, Aptana, DreamWeaver, and of course Notepad who for one reason or another do not meet my requirements (Komodo and DreamWeaver, Aptana bulky and have a lot of excess, Aptana can not normally look for files, Notepad does not have a normal avtocomplete and important - they all look gloomy). Sublime Text 2 similar, but it is far to the normal html editor.
Advise something ... :(
I would be very grateful. I'm sure many were asked a similar question and found quite tolerable solution.
By the way - maybe there is a ported version?

http://www.panic.com/coda/

Comment: Notepad looks "gloomy"? Weird... And unfortunately, no, there is neither a Windows port of Coda nor anything that is even remotely equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PC equivalent of Coda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869886/pc-equivalent-of-coda)

Answer (score 7):

How about [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), then? It features a sleek Live Preview in Chrome, too. You won't need to reload pages to see your changes in CSS, HTML & JavaScript anymore!

To me, [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is by far the best code editor for Windows (also with Linux and Mac versions).
Read why at Jammy's [Journey to the Perfect Text-Editor.](http://css-plus.com/2012/02/my-journey-to-the-perfect-text-editor/)

- Multiple Selections to rename variables quickly.
- Batch edits with Multiple Selections.
- Command Palette for fast access to functionality.
- Goto Anything to quickly navigate between files.
- Goto Anything to show a function, line or word within a file.
- Find and Replace with regular expressions.
- Split Editing to edit files side by side, or edit two locations in the same file.
- Distraction Free Mode in full screen for chrome free editing.
- Instant Project Switch
- Cross Platform
- Plugin API

> **Screenshot[image: Screenshot]**

Answer (score 1):

You can try Kompozer (a Mozilla project):- http://kompozer.net/

Quoting from Kompozer's site:-

> KompoZer is a complete web authoring system that combines web file management and easy-to-use WYSIWYG web page editing.

Or if it is just source code editors, see this list of alternatives:- http://alternativeto.net/software/coda/

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice one. Nothing compared to coda, but it tries to.

http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [code::blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/). It's simple yet powerful, and the user interface is easy enough to get around in. It also supports many types of files.

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Before I switched to Coda I was using jEdit. http://www.jedit.org/

jEdit required some tweaking for me to really enjoy it. There are lots of plugins that you can install easily inside the app. If I remember correctly I would add File Browser, Console, and Buffer Tabs. The file browser does support FTP/SFTP as well as local browsing. The console can be placed anywhere on screen alongside your code. I don't believe I've ever tried an autocomplete plugin for it but I did see it exists.

Works on Windows, Linux, and Mac too.

Answer (score 0):

so far this editor is the best , simple powerful and clear all in one web developpment [tool for windows](http://www.coffeecup.com/html-editor/)